# Android key signing on Windows for React Expo app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm currently following this tutorial (https://medium.com/@inaguirre/react-native-login-with-google-quick-guide-fe351e464752) to add "Login with Google." I got the OAuth client ID working for iOS, but for Android, it requires an SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.
[image]

I tried:

```
openssl rand -base64 32 | openssl sha1 -c
```

and (I replaced the "path-to-debug-or-production-keystore" with the full file path)

```
keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

but neither of these work. A lot of advices given online is from the context of using Android Studio, but I'm using VS Code for an Expo app.

I get this error when I run the second, keytool command in the Command Prompt & PowerShell.

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\User\Desktop\app
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\User\Desktop\app
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried running

```
keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

within the folder that contains the keytool.exe file within the Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241 folder, but same error.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in app directory:

cd android && ./gradlew signingReport

Copy the sha1 with debug variant.